# Recursive aggregate at BigQuery

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I have the data below in a BigQuery table:

```
subscription_id         subscription_source_id
1                       NULL
2                       NULL
3                       1
4                       3
5                       2
6                       NULL
```

And I need to aggregate the rows by parent, generating an array with the children by parent, like this:

```
subscription_id         subscription_children
---------------------------------------------
1                       3
                        4
---------------------------------------------                   
2                       5
---------------------------------------------
6                       null
```

Do you have any clue about how can I get this result only using BigQuery functions?

Best,

Comment: Is the depth of the data structure always going to be 1 like in your example, or do you need to support arbitrary depth e.g. `1 -> 3` and `3 -> 7` and `3 -> 9` and `7 ->10`? I ask because if it's one layer deep this can be done in SQL, but if there is arbitrary depth then it gets more complex.

Comment: Do you mean ARRAY_AGG? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg